# Repeat currency symbol in a contributions list

Tags: mailing

I would like to send a classic mailing to our donors which lists the contributions of the previous fiscal year [following this guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/#thank-you-letters).

But the list I obtain, only have the currency symbol near the first contribution.

[image]

And even in the above-mentioned guide, the currency symbol appears only near the first contribution:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this and have currency symbol near each of the contributions listed?

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, I notice that the documentation you point to shows the same behaviour:
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/#grouped-contribution-thank-you-letters
So it appears to have been how that feature works since inception.

Comment: Yes it does. As said, "even in the above-mentioned guide, the currency symbol appears only near the first contribution". But it's a weird behaviour because there's no point in having the currency symbol just in the first contribution.

Comment: Yes, its not handled properly in code.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: "yes".

And the longer answer is: dig into the code and submit a PR, or hire someone to do that.